# How to convert my date format to another format

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

My Date for mat is below

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

My out >> `20200607-080127`

I need `timestr` above to convert to  `07/06/2020 08:01:27`

I need to use `timestr` only to convert

Comment: `time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H%M%S")`?

Comment: This should do it - time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_str = '20200607-080127'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
print(type(datetime_object))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the following:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
>>> timestr
'07/06/2020 17:08:31'
```

`datetime` is recommended over `time` because there are a few formatting strings that are not supported by `time`, but work just find with `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify every format you want, so for your desired output use:

```
time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

You can do all sort of stuff like:

```
time.strftime("%d//%m//%Y %H~%M~%S")
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

Please add the required separators.

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(timestr)
```